# openstack all in one environment, instance can't access service running in docker container

Tags: docker, openstack

I have an openstack all in one environment deployed, IP 192.168.11.103.
and started an instance, bind a floating IP to the instance. fixed IP 10.0.1.11, floating IP 192.168.11.56.

From within the instance, I can access the services in the host, like "ssh 192.168.11.103" works fine. It is OK to visit internet services.

And then in the host, I started docker container to run my mongo service:
844e6f81ecf5   mongo:20160818  "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   4 hours ago  Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp

Here I can't access the mongo service from my instance:
mongo --host 192.168.11.103
Failed to connect to 192.168.11.103:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.

But I can access the service from the openstack host 192.168.11.103 or from another client. e.g. 192.168.11.5.

What happened here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check iptables or firewalld on instance and host? Try stopping those services and retest...